# Banshee won't start unless run as sudo or -debug

Tags: sound, banshee, sudo, debug

I have no idea what is going on, I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu and then after a reboot Banshee won't start. I began to poke around the forums and then tried running it as sudo and with `-debug`, both of which get it to start, but with this error

```
[Info  21:21:37.788] Running Banshee 2.2.1: [Ubuntu 11.10 (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2011-12-19 14:58:04 UTC]
(Banshee:9910): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Banshee:9910): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Banshee:9910): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Banshee:9910): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[Warn  21:21:38.332] DBus support could not be started. Disabling for this session. - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Exception: Unable to open the session message bus. (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.BusG.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName, Boolean init) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Info  21:21:39.748] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Warn  21:21:41.085] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  21:21:41.085] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  21:21:41.087] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  21:21:41.087] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.

(Banshee:9910): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'CloseAction' to action group 'Global'
[Warn  21:21:41.151] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  21:21:41.151] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  21:21:41.151] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  21:21:41.152] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  21:21:41.155] All services are started 2.819477
[Info  21:21:41.776] AmazonMP3 store redirect URL: https://one.ubuntu.com/music/store/amz/
[Info  21:21:42.438] nereid Client Started
[Info  21:21:42.597] GStreamer version 0.10.35.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False

(Banshee:9910): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.UL3G7V': No such file or directory
```

please do help, I would love to be able to run banshee.

**EDIT:** I ran Banshee again regularly (As recommended by cosmorogers), without sudo or `-debug` and got a different readout:

```
[Info  06:58:41.576] Running Banshee 2.2.1: [Ubuntu 11.10 (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2011-12-19 14:58:04 UTC]
(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

Comment: Some of these are because you are running it as root (sudo)

What happens if you just run banshee from a terminal (without sudo or -debug).

Comment: Hey cosmorogers, thank you for responding! I ran it regularly and then I got `[Info  06:58:41.576] Running Banshee 2.2.1: [Ubuntu 11.10 (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2011-12-19 14:58:04 UTC]

(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Banshee:2111): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",` after the last bit printed into the terminal it stopped.

Comment: Hmmmm....
Try installing gtk2-engines-pixbuf (`sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf`) see if that helps... If not have you tried reinstalling banshee?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!